# Nested bootstrap js buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of javascript buttons nested within another set of javascript buttons. Below is my fiddle.

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" style="padding: 20px;">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="btn btn-info" style="padding: 20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP101" data-duration="7" />1</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP102" data-duration="14" />2</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP103" data-duration="21" />3</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP104" data-duration="28" />4</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="btn btn-info" style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP201" data-duration="7" />1</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP202" data-duration="14" />2</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP203" data-duration="21" />3</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="package" value="RP204" data-duration="28" />4</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4xLs9f8/

My issue is that when I click the top level button, it logs out the nested radio button as if it was already selected. I don't have anything marked as selected or checked.

Does nesting buttons like this cause problems?

Comment: Your code doesn't match the fiddle, and the fiddle doesn't have nested radio groups.

Comment: Apologies. needed to redact sensitive information and forgot to paste back into SO.

Comment: Nestability certainly wasn't a consideration when Bootstrap's btns were designed. And, for example, you can't really nest `<button>`s or `<a>`s in vanilla HTML.

Comment: I talked the project manager into a different approach. Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting is certainly not intended. What happens is that it the javascript is selecting the last radio input in the group and selects that.